# How do I perform an electrochemical impedance spectroscopy test for battery?

Tags: impedance

I have tried to look online for procedures to perform this test but couldn’t find anything. So if anyone can refer me to a set of procedures or give me procedures that I can use to perform the test and make plots (Bode or Nyquist plot), it would be really helpful

Comment: I guess there are some manufacturers that sell battery testers. All of them are not willing to share the principles of test procedure. Perhaps it could be used a  sweep generator with current/voltage measurement.